# Confused about json_decode and results I'm getting

Tags: php, json

### I have a simple script that gets a json result:

```
$postURL = $URL;
$json = file_get_contents($postURL);
$obj = json_decode($json);
print_r ($json);
```

the `print_r` gives me a blank, as does `echo $obj->{'name'}`

I suspect I may be handling the result improperly. I need help - just need to be able to grab a single key/value from the object using `$obj->{'name'}`.

### My result from file_get_contents looks like this:

```
GET d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e Mon, 16 Dec 2013 09:47:07 GMT 
/targets/32feaf056b8c46e4a6f5500b6289cf59{"target_record":
{"target_id":"32feaf056b8c46e4a6f5500b6289cf59","name":"Francesca
Grace","width":300.0,"active_flag":true,"tracking_rating":5,"reco_rating":""},
 "status":"success","result_code":"Success",
"transaction_id":"d5f6be0a66af4e3d84d00ad4cb1ac2e3"}
```

Comment: You assign the contents to `$json` then you decode `$jsonstring`...

Comment: echo "name=".$obj->{'name'} returns blank

Comment: Your file_get_contents output is not pure json format.
You have "GET d41d8cd98f00... .. " in the beginning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is an example of json with google rates system:

```
$data = file_get_contents('http://rate-exchange.appspot.com/currency?from=GBP&to=EUR');
$resultat = json_decode($data, true);
echo $resultat["rate"];
```

Comment: This produces a **completely** different result than what I have. Any ideas?

Comment: can you give us the url to see what's displaying with browser?

Comment: URL to get the result: http://case42.com/ogle/GetTarget.php?targetid=32feaf056b8c46e4a6f5500b6289cf59

Comment: I'm trying to decode this, then grab a single key/value from it, like {'name'}

Comment: this is not a valid json answer, you should try to crop the left part of the answer to {"target_record

Comment: Well, I guess that _would_ be the easiest way.  I've been trying to figure out why I'm getting such a funky response from the server - I suspect the code generating the json is also setting headers.   THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

```
$postURL = $URL;
$json = file_get_contents($postURL);
$obj = json_decode($json);
print_r ($obj);
```

Comment: The OP has stated in comments that it was a typo and the problem persists. (Not the downvoter, just speculating).